# PHP - with extension/unextension link regex for Rewrite

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

first of all my english is not so good by i think will be enough.

So, i have this rule, and it working with unextension links(localhost/abc)

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/]+)$ Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=$1

http ://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim
---> http ://127.0.0.1/Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=Bilgilerim

http ://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim/dasdasd/asdasd/asdasd
---> http://127.0.0.1/Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=Bilgilerim/dasdasd/asdasd/asdasd
```

But i want to use sometimes an extension chars like '.xx'. I tryd to do that with this **^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/]+)$.?** but i didnt make it.
So if any solution for this

```
http://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim
---> http://127.0.0.1/Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=Bilgilerim
http://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim.xx
---> http://127.0.0.1/Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=Bilgilerim.xx

http://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim/dasdasd/asdasd/asdasd
---> http://127.0.0.1/Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=Bilgilerim/dasdasd/asdasd/asdasd
http://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim.xx/dasdasd/asdasd/asdasd
---> http://127.0.0.1/Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=Bilgilerim.xx/dasdasd/asdasd/asdasd
```

please share me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=$1 [L]
```

Note: `RewriteCond` line prevents existing files (like your css files) to be rewritten

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a period to your character class:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/.]+)$ Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=$1
```

This will enable rewriting for the URLs you mention -

`http://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim.xx`

`http://127.0.0.1:84/Bilgilerim.xx/dasdasd/asdasd/asdasd`

Hope that helps

Comment: i did use it, it working but all links are changing. i mean for example style.css is my global style file. it opening like http://127.0.0.1/Sayfalar.php?Sayfa=style.css . can u suggest any solution :/